# Show that if $f$ is integrable and $g \le f$, then $g$ is integrable?

Tags: calculus

Let  $f,g :  R ⊆ \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ functions such that  $0 \le g(x) \le f(x) $   $\forall x \in R  $ , f is integrable and  $ \int_R f= 0  $ prove that  $g $ is integrable and  $\int_R g=0 $

My thoughts:

$inf(g) \le inf(f)$ and $sup(g)\le sup(f)$ $\forall x \in R$

Let P partition of R. Let
$m_i= inf \{ f(x) :  x \in R_i \}$
$m'_i= inf \{ g(x) :  x \in R_i \}$ and
$M_i= sup \{ f(x) :  x \in R_i \}$
$M'_i= sup \{ g(x) :  x \in R_i \}$

$\implies$ $0\le m'_i \le m_i$ and
$0\le M'_i \le M_i$

$\implies$ $0\le L(g,P) \le L(f,P)$ and $0\le U(g,P) \le U(f,P)$ for all P partitions of rectangle R
$\implies$ $0\le \int_\_g \le\int_\_f $ and the same for upper integrals 
but $f$ is integrable and equal to $0$ so $g$ is integrable and equal to  $0$.
is that right?

Comment: I want to prove that g is integrable and is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that $g$ is integrable, and integrates to $0$. Since we know that $g(x) \geq 0$, this amounts to showing the following:

> For any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $P$ of $\Bbb R$ such that
>   $$
> \sum_{I \in P}|I|\cdot\sup_{x \in I}g(x)< \epsilon\tag{*}
> $$
>   (or $U(g, P) < \epsilon$, if you will)

We know that for any interval $I$, we have
$$
\sup_{x \in I}g(x) \leq \sup_{x \in I} f(x)\tag{1}
$$
 Also, $f$ is integrable, and integrates to $0$, so we know that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $P$ of $\Bbb R$ such that the following holds for $f$, and an:
$$
\sum_{I \in P}|I|\cdot\sup_{x \in I}f(x)< \epsilon\tag{2}
$$
Can you stitch together $\text{(1)}$ and $\text{(2)}$ to prove $\text{(*)}$?

Comment: Using (1) and (2) we have U(g,P)<U(f,P) so U(g,P)<ϵ?

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f\ge 0$ and $\int f=0$ imply $f=0$ a.e. Additionally, subsets of zero set are measurable and have measure $0$.

Comment: Yes, thats right.  Thanks